# Get every n-th line from text-file, reverse it and print out

Tags: java

I writing function which get: file-path and number as parameters.
Function open this file and get every n-th line from it, reverse it and print out to console.

Until now i manage to do something like:

```
public static void reverseText(String filePath, int colle) // int colle = n-th line
{
    BufferedReader fileRead = null;

    String line;        

    try
    {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (!(file.exists()))
            file.createNewFile();

        fileRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((line = fileRead.readLine()) != null)
        { 

        }


        fileRead.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I mean is that in file for example are following lines of text (int colle = 2, so we get every 2nd line form file)

`first line
 second line` <-- this 
`third line
 fourth line` <-- and this

(read file and reverse get lines) --> Output print out in console:

"enil dnoces"
"enil htruof"

I guess for reverse I should use StringBuilder but first i need get these lines and I have no idea how to read every n-th line...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use a line counter and the modulo operator.

Comment: You will still read every line, but only process every n-th line.

Comment: Yeah... that it's. Good idea and it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use line counter to control loop iterations:

```
int n = 3;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; (line = fileRead.readLine()) != null; i++) {
     if (i % n == 0) {
        sb.delete(0, line.length())
        System.out.println(sb.append(line).reverse());
     }
}
```

You still can do it using `while` defining a variable for that.

Comment: I think there's a bit of trouble translating the requirements into code here. If someones says "print every third line" and the lines are "one\ntwo\three\n\four\nfive\nsix", they would expect "three\nsix"

Answer (score 1):

Solution below read all lines and then select every n-line, reverse and print.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int frequency = 5;
    final List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/home/test.txt"));
    List<String> collect = IntStream.range(0, strings.size())
            .filter(c -> c % frequency == 0)
            .mapToObj(c -> strings.get(c))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    collect.forEach(str ->
            System.out.println(new StringBuilder(str).reverse())
    );
}
```

IntStream is necessary to get specific lines from collection strings.
Then one by one lines are reversed and printed. It can be one liner but decided to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks dude! I appreciated your reply but to be honest I'm not too advanced in Java yet, and I don't understand more than half of your code.  I'm taking the first steps into object oriented programming. I will try figured out every line of your code with Java instruction help.

Comment: I think there's a bit of trouble translating the requirements into code here. If someones says "print every third line" and the lines are "one\ntwo\three\n\four\nfive\nsix", they would expect "three\nsix".

Comment: @l1m4k The code _is_ different but shouldn't be considered advanced. The key terms are: readAllLines, filter frequency, forEach, print, reverse, which is pretty close to the way you wrote the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for help. Below i posted working code for my expectations

```
public static void reverseText(String filePath, int colle)
{   
    BufferedReader fileRead = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int lineCounter = 0;
    String line;      

    try
    {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (!(file.exists()))
                file.createNewFile();

        fileRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((line = fileRead.readLine()) != null)
        { 
            lineCounter++;
            if (lineCounter %colle == 0)
            {
                builder.delete(0, line.length());
                System.out.println(builder.append(line).reverse());
            } 
        }

        fileRead.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```